# How do you export a dataframe to an exisiting, formatted csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to export a dataframe to an exisiting,formatted csv file but the dataframe keeps on getting appended in a vertical form along with additional headers which should horizontal.

```py
A B C D E F
1 2 3 4 5 6   #=-> This is the format I have in my exisiting csv file

A B C D E F
1 2 3 4 5 6
x x x x x x   #-> This is how I want to do it

A B C D E F
1 2 3 4 5 6
A 1
B 2
C 3 
D 4  #-> This is what's currently happening
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```py
df.iloc[location].to_csv(path,mode='a')
```

This is the code that I've been trying with.

Comment: read file to dataframe, add rows in dataframe, save all in file.

Answer (score 4):

`df.iloc[location]` can gives you `Series` which is treated different then `DataFrame`

You would have to convert it to `DataFrame` but using list with this `Series` to get data in row instead of column

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [df.iloc[location]] )
```

and then save to csv without header

```
df.to_csv(path, mode='a', header=None)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also convert `Series` to `DataFrame` using `.to_frame()` and then use `.T` to transpose column to row

```
df = df.iloc[location].to_frame().T
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply in advance. I've tried the df = df.iloc[location].to_frame().T which seems to have partially done the job! But I also was wondering how I would paste the row in to the desired row? in this case, i want to entirely replace the 2nd row. Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely replace but add my exported data to 2nd row 2nd column

Comment: if you want replace anything in file then you have to read all data to dataframe, replace it in dataframe and save all data again in file.

Comment: that sounds brilliant! Would you know any ways to replace the dataframe? Thank you!!

Comment: or I can just add from 2nd row 2nd column as I already have a value for 2nd row 1st column

Comment: file doesn't have method to find where is start of second column, and it doesn't have method to move other elements when you want to put longer or shorter item and there are elements in third row. You will have to read all to memory (DataFrame), edit it and write all again in file.

Comment: sounds good. Then how would I replace the second row in the dataframe, if you know for any chance! thanks a lot

Comment: as i only have 2 rows in my exisiting csv file, I only want concat the first row with my exported row

Comment: replace row in dataframe ie. `df.iloc[1] = [1,4,5,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 2):

The situation you want this to happen in is unclear, but one good generic method is to

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(...)      # Read the file.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(...)     # Make a DataFrame of the new entries you want to add.
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])  # Concatenate the two.
df.to_csv(...)              # Write the file to the original directory.
```

Comment: Im trying to export a specific row from a dataframe to the 2nd row of an exisiting csv file

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[location].T.to_csv('filename.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=False)
```